# How to disable TFS 2010 CodeAnalysis Checkin Policy on sub folders?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have created a Team Project in TFS 2010, call it MyProject. Under that I have 2 folder Src & Tests. I created a Checkin Policy requiring ChangeSet comments (TFS Power Tools is installed on all concerned machines) and Code Analysis. I want Code Analysis to run on projects under Src, but I don't want to require Code Analysis on projects under Tests. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Beezler

Answer (score 3):

I receieved the answer on another thread.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsadmin/thread/9ea93c0f-e0fc-4677-89c8-b2efb07504c6

0- If you dont yet, install the tfs power tools

1- Add the main rule (in your case the code analysis rule)

2- Add a Custom Path policy rule with the path that you want the policy to be evaluated (src)

3- link the custom path to the main rule

4- Disable the main rule, if not, it will be evaluated twice